# Controls overlapping Scrollbar

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In IE 7 (haven't tested against other versions of IE), when I resize the browswer, the scrollbars in one of the iframes on my page become active (as I want).

However the controls which are visible on the page (textboxes, divs with borders) overlap the (horizontal & vertical) scrollbars. It's as if they have a higher z-index that that of the scrollbar.

Does someone know what I can do to ensure this doesn't happen?

[Screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c45a9d78a3.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c45a9d78a3.png)

Comment: if you truly see this with iframes (not frames), please add a URL or some source to test with.  I've only seen this with framesets.

Comment: the entire codebase isn't mine so I did double check this.There are no <frame> or <frameset> tags anywhere in my source & none are generated on the fly. i.e. doing a view source shows neither of these tags.when i try to put together a simple couple of pages to demo this it doesn't happen of course!

Comment: I should add that the elements overlapping the scrollbar are positioned absolutely and are also resized dynamically in the code behind file (if that information is relevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed scrolling property on iframe to be auto rather than yes and scrollbars are behaving as expected.

```
<iframe class="frmProperty" height="100%" frameborder="0" id="ifrmProperty" name="ifrmProperty" width="100%" scrolling="auto" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a known regression when IE7 was released (occurs in IE8 too) that MS rejected (from their kinda-public bug tracker)

this ***only happens*** with **<frames>** in IE7 or IE8

**<iframe>** is OK.

Basically using framesets and IE7+ is a royal pain.  I would highly recommend against it.